# How to implement a Muller C-element in a LUT4 of a FPGA?

Tags: fpga, circuit-design

I am practicing Asynchronous circuit design, and I would like to have some simple experiments by building simple circuits using a Spartan-3 FPGA.

I am wondering how one can implement a 2-input and 4-input Muller C-element into a FPGA using LUT4 primitives?

Will it be hazard free?

Comment: I don't know. But I suspect you'll be out in the tall grass as far as the synth tools etc are concerned - the focus is strongly on synchronous design so expect tool problems galore in the "less well explored" areas...

Comment: Yes, it is not very well explored. That is why I have picked up this for my PhD thesis.

Comment: Why did you chose such an old FPGA? What's a Muller C element?

Comment: The type of FPGA does not really matter here. I am trying to build up primitive logic gates necessary for constructing an asynchronous circuit. After I become successful constructing those, then I can get a modern FPGA which offers more LUTs (But still the principles  are the same). You can find the Muller C gate definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-element

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should be possible to implement up to a 3 input C element on a Spartan 3. On a Spartan 6 with 6 input LUTs, you should be able to implement 5 input C elements. Now, I'm not entirely sure if the synthesizer will handle the feedback path correctly or not. I would recommend synthesizing a single gate and then check the mapped schematic to ensure that it is implemented correctly. If that doesn't work, then you may have to directly instantiate LUT primitives for your C elements. This probably won't be so bad if you just do it once for a C element module that you can use many times. The other problem could be the routing of the feedback path. Not sure that could be done about that though. Maybe setting maxdelay would help. Maybe not. You'll just have to do some experimenting.

Now, timing driven place and route is an entirely different animal. I have no idea how that will work with an asynchronous design. The result could be very sub-optimal.

Comment: There are several papers out there suggesting to instantiate LUT4 primitive, and prove that if only one input changes at a time and a single LUT is used, then the C-element is guaranteed to be hazard free. One  example is this: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5349341&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5349341 .

Comment: I became successful building a single Muller gate, using a single LUT4. Now I am baffled about how to ensure only single input change at a time on the gate (assuming a 2-input Muller gate). I give you +1 for mentioning setting a time constraint on feedback route.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a C-element on LUT-based FPGAs can be done, although it is not very simple. The logical functionality is the easy part. For example, to create a 2-input C-element with inputs A and B and output C, it suffices to implement a OR-AND network (you can do this with an FPGA LUT4) where C is the output of a 3-input AND and each of the inputs of this AND connects to the output of a 2-input AND. In the first AND, the inputs are A and B, in the second AND the inputs are A and C and the last AND has as inputs B and C. The tricky part is to implement the feedback wire (C to both 2nd and 3rd ANDs) in a way that the OR output to the AND inputs forks (wire derivations to multiple places) are "isochronic", i.e. in a way that the delays in all branches of the feedback wire are within some computed bound. You can find more about how to achieve this in a paper we wrote about the implementation of asynchronous controllers in FPGA (published in the ICCD conference in 2007), available at (http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~calazans/publications/2007_ICCD_Julian.pdf). A 4-input C-element can be designed likewise, but you will need at least a LUT5 (4 inputs plus the feedback wire), or you can build it combining some 2-input C-elements.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 types of C-elements, one is RS-latch based and another is generic gate based one. Here is the example of generic gate based one:

```
module Celement(reset, A1, A2, Z);
    input reset, A1, A2;
    output Z;
        LUT4 #(.INIT(16'h00E8))
        LUT4_inst (
        .O(Z),
        .I0(A1),  
        .I1(A2),  
        .I2(Z),
        .I3(reset)
    );
```

Comment: While logically making sense, is this tolerant to glitches?